# How to convert dataURL to file object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileapi

I need to convert a dataURL to a File object in Javascript in order to send it over using AJAX. Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how.

Comment: cwallenpoole, its a big code,everything before it works fine as the images are appended to the body,just tell me what you need and i'll post it here

Comment: What is `formData` in your script/page?

Comment: Since you are using toDataURL it gets the canvas image as a b64 encoded string not a file.Since you are using "POST" that is why it is being stored in $_POST. "but that would be an ugly hack" it's not an ugly hack it's how the file is created.

Comment: formdata has been initialized as the following in the block which contains these two functions,
    var formdata = new FormData();

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you need to send it over ajax, then there's no need to use a `File` object, only `Blob` and `FormData` objects are needed.

As I sidenote, why don't you just send the base64 string to the server over ajax and convert it to binary server-side, using PHP's `base64_decode` for example? Anyway, the standard-compliant code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata) works in Chrome 13 and WebKit nightlies:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    //Old Code
    //write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    //var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    //bb.append(ab);
    //return bb.getBlob(mimeString);

    //New Code
    return new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});


}
```

Then just append the blob to a new FormData object and post it to your server using ajax:

```
var blob = dataURItoBlob(someDataUrl);
var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

fd.append("myFile", blob);
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I have already made something like that and it works fine. Its a canvas based image resizer, watermarker and uploader. Waiting for a project to use it on

Comment: In Firefox, if there's no form, FormData should be created as: `new FormData();` Otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: Why do you have a `callback` argument here? It seems you should remove it.

Comment: Hi, just thought to mention I have a slightly modernized version available at http://www.nixtu.info/2013/06/how-to-upload-canvas-data-to-server.html .

Comment: Thanks for your help @bebraw I have read in your blog that ArrayBuffer is deprecated and it is recommended the use of DataView. It would be nice that you update your code.

Comment: @ccsakuweb Yeah. I'll do that in the near future. Thanks for poking. :)

Comment: @ccsakuweb Done. I made it use DataView now. In my tests it yielded same results so I guess it's ok.

Comment: BlobBuilder is now deprecated and does not work anymore in Chrome !

Comment: This post uses deprecated elements such as BlobBuilder, see @cuixiping's answer for a working solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that the base64 encoding of a file is often substantially larger than the actual file, which means a lot more data is transmitted when using base64 as compared to `multipart/form-data`, which is what you get when you use `File`.

Comment: FWIW, the "write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer" step can be `const ab = Uint8Array.from(byteString, ch => ch.charCodeAt(0)).buffer;`.

Comment: I've shared the same experience in my post here https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-pass-file-into-an-iframe-and-convert-it-to-blob-for-further-ajax-request/

Comment: @AlexFilatov Invalid link

Comment: Can anyone pinpoint what answer is being referenced in the comments? This ID now just references this question, and not an answer. This answer is also copy/pasted several times; none of which removing this now dead reference.

Comment: Dude you literally saved my hackathon 11 years later.

Answer (score 58):

The [BlobBuilder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) is deprecated and should no longer be used. Use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead of old BlobBuilder. The code is very clean and simple.

File object is inherit from Blob object. You can use both of them with FormData object.

```
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
}
```

use dataURLtoBlob() function to convert dataURL to blob and send ajax to server.

for example:

```
var dataurl = 'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=';
var blob = dataURLtoBlob(dataurl);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", blob, "hello.txt");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/server.php', true);
xhr.onload = function(){
    alert('upload complete');
};
xhr.send(fd);
```

---

**Another way:**

You can also use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) to convert an url to a file object (file object has name/fileName property, this is different from blob object)

The code is very short and easy to use.   `(works in Chrome and Firefox)`

```
//load src and convert to a File instance object
//work for any type of src, not only image src.
//return a promise that resolves with a File instance

function srcToFile(src, fileName, mimeType){
    return (fetch(src)
        .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
        .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], fileName, {type:mimeType});})
    );
}
```

Usage example 1: Just convert to file object

```
srcToFile(
    'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=',
    'hello.txt',
    'text/plain'
)
.then(function(file){
    console.log(file);
})
```

Usage example 2: Convert to file object and upload to server

```
srcToFile(
    'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=',
    'hello.txt',
    'text/plain'
)
.then(function(file){
    console.log(file);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", file);
    return fetch('/server.php', {method:'POST', body:fd});
})
.then(function(res){
    return res.text();
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
;
```

Comment: I really enjoyed your answer as it's neat and clean, but I really can figure out the usage of ArrayBuffer in other answers. Would you please explain the usage if ArrayBuffer and why it's not used here?

Comment: In case you didn't check out the Mozilla Developer Network reference, fetch is an experimental feature and is not recommended for use in production code.  Too bad, looks cool.

Comment: how this would be without promise version ?

Answer (score 41):

To create a blob from a dataURL:

```
const response = await fetch(dataURL);
const blob = await response.blob();
```

To create a file from a blob:

```
const file = new File(
  [blob],
  "fileName.jpg",
  {
    type: "image/jpeg",
    lastModified: new Date()
  }
);
```

Comment: No need for 2 awaits and nesting. `await fetch(src).then(it => it.blob())`

Comment: @StevenSpungin Better yet, break the code onto two explicit lines, as I've done as an edit to the answer. Mixing `await` and `then` often leads to confusion and arguably isn't much better than nesting `await`s. We don't have to write it on one line.

Comment: You can still put the .then on another line, and it is also arguably better to not create an itermediate variable and const declaration.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to convert the dataURL into `File` object.

You need to convert the dataURL into `Blob` then convert the `Blob` into `File`.
The function is from answer by Matthew. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261048/13647044)

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
      // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
      // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
      var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

      // separate out the mime component
      var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

      // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
    }

const blob = dataURItoBlob(url);
const resultFile = new File([blob], "file_name");
```

Other than that, you can have options on the `File` Object initialised. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) to File() constructor.

```
const resultFile = new File([blob], "file_name",{type:file.type,lastModified:1597081051454});
```

The type should be `[MIME][1]` type(i.e. `image/jpeg`) and last modified value in my example is equivalent to `Mon Aug 10 2020 19:37:31 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`

Answer (score 1):

In Latest browsers:

```js
const dataURLtoBlob = (dataURL) => {
        fetch(dataURL)
            .then(res => res.blob())
            .then(blob => console.log(blob))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: Basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65669404/6243352), except in a confusing function that only logs the blob to the console rather than return it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I arrived on this one:

```js
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var dw = new DataView(ab);
    for(var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        dw.setUint8(i, byteString.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    return new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
}

module.exports = dataURItoBlob;
```