# Blob from DataURL?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

Using `FileReader`'s `readAsDataURL()` I can transform arbitrary data into a Data URL.  Is there way to convert a Data URL back into a `Blob` instance using builtin browser apis?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

User Matt has proposed the following code a year ago ( [How to convert dataURL to file object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850276/how-to-convert-dataurl-to-file-object-in-javascript) ) which might help you

EDIT: As some commenters reported, BlobBuilder has been deprecated some time ago. This is the updated code:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
  // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

  // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);

  // create a view into the buffer
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

  // set the bytes of the buffer to the correct values
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
  var blob = new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
  return blob;

}
```

Comment: The duplicated split seems a bit wasteful, given that this could be a very large string.

Comment: What is the role of the variable "ia" - its assigned a value but is never used in forming the blob. Why?

Comment: Same question as @Blaze, why is the iteration over `ia` necessary? @devnull69

Comment: Blaze, Ward: ia is a *view* of the buffer. So when you set each byte in ia, it is writing into the buffer. Without the loop over ia the buffer will be completely empty.

Comment: How do I find SO answer #6850276  ?

Comment: This has some additional code for cases where the dataURI isn't encoding base64 data: https://gist.github.com/andipaetzold/d88f29caa0ddb3566759

Comment: @BT : I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407840/271577 is intended (note the redirected URL includes "#6850276").

Comment: I think this should be `var blob = new Blob([ia], ...);`

Comment: FWIW, we can create the `ArrayBuffer` more directly: `Uint8Array.from(byteString, ch => ch.charCodeAt(0)).buffer`.

Comment: `atob()` is marked incorrectly as deprecated in vscode. `window.atob()` is a workaround.

Comment: NOTE: this code does not consider malformed URIs. You should first check whether the string starts with `data:` and just to be sure, try-catch it. Otherwise you'll crash your app

Answer (score 94):

Like @Adria method but with Fetch api and just smaller [[caniuse?](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)]
Don't have to think about mimetype since blob response type just works out of the box

> Warning: Can violate the Content Security Policy (CSP)
>   ...if you use that stuff

```js
var url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => console.log(blob))
```

Don't think you could do it any smaller then this without using lib's

Comment: Very elegant. Unfortunately edge 13 and safari doesn't support "fetch".

Comment: It is supported in edge 14 and safari 10.1

Comment: Async version: `const blob = await (await fetch(url)).blob();`

Comment: Works great, but the file doesn't have an extension when read from server. Any thoughts?

Comment: The bigger problem of this `fetch` is it force to having a async API.

Answer (score 53):

In [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) one can use the one liner suggested by Christian d'Heureuse in a comment:

```js
const blob = await (await fetch(dataURI)).blob();
```

Comment: One caveat with this approach is that this could violate your content security policy (CSP), if your application has any.

Comment: Adding to what @standielpls commented, you'll have to add `connect-src data:` to your Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 21):

```
dataURItoBlob : function(dataURI, dataTYPE) {
        var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]), array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: dataTYPE});
    }
```

input dataURI is Data URL and dataTYPE is the file type and then output blob object

Comment: The `dataTYPE` is embedded in `dataURI` and hence should be parsed as in the first answer.

Comment: dataURL2Blob has come from my plugin for image process, you can check out this link. I just copy my own code.
https://github.com/xenophon566/html5.upload/blob/master/js/imageUtility.js

Answer (score 12):

XHR based method.

```
function dataURLtoBlob( dataUrl, callback )
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest;

    req.open( 'GET', dataUrl );
    req.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // Can't use blob directly because of https://crbug.com/412752

    req.onload = function fileLoaded(e)
    {
        // If you require the blob to have correct mime type
        var mime = this.getResponseHeader('content-type');

        callback( new Blob([this.response], {type:mime}) );
    };

    req.send();
}

dataURLtoBlob( 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', function( blob )
{
    console.log( blob );
});
```

Comment: Seems, this is the best way now. Thank you!

Comment: Will not work in Safari - it will throw cross-origin error if page is loaded from HTTPS.

Comment: The question is **Blob from DataURL?**

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    if(typeof dataURI !== 'string'){
        throw new Error('Invalid argument: dataURI must be a string');
    }
    dataURI = dataURI.split(',');
    var type = dataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0],
        byteString = atob(dataURI[1]),
        byteStringLength = byteString.length,
        arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteStringLength),
        intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteStringLength; i++) {
        intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([intArray], {
        type: type
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since none of these answers support base64 and non-base64 dataURLs, here's one that does based on vuamitom's deleted answer:

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135417/download-canvas-as-png-in-fabric-js-giving-network-error/
var dataURLtoBlob = exports.dataURLtoBlob = function(dataurl) {
    var parts = dataurl.split(','), mime = parts[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1]
    if(parts[0].indexOf('base64') !== -1) {
        var bstr = atob(parts[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n)
        while(n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n)
        }

        return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime})
    } else {
        var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1])
        return new Blob([raw], {type: mime})
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if there are *other* dataURL mime types that might have to be handled differently. But please let me know if you find out! Its possible that dataURLs can simply have any format they want, and in that case it'd be up to you to find the right code for your particular use case.

Answer (score 2):

### Create a blob using [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest):

```js
function dataURLtoBlob( dataUrl, callback )
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest;

    req.open( 'GET', dataUrl );
    req.responseType = 'blob';

    req.onload = function fileLoaded(e)
    {
        callback(this.response);
    };

    req.send();
}

var dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

dataURLtoBlob(dataURI , function( blob )
{
    console.log( blob );
});
```

Comment: Chrome throws net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 1):

Refactored version of the accepted answer.

```
// NOTE: This function doesn't handle URLEncoded Data URLs.
// Data URL format – data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
function dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl: string): Blob {
  const [meta, data] = dataUrl.split(",")

  // Convert the base64 encoded data to a binary string.
  const byteString = atob(data)

  // Get the MIME type.
  const [mimeTypeWithDataPrefix] = meta.split(";")
  const mimeType = mimeTypeWithDataPrefix.replace("data:", "")

  // Convert the binary string to an ArrayBuffer.
  const arrayBuffer = Uint8Array.from(byteString, (c) => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer

  // Create a blob from the ArrayBuffer.
  return new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: mimeType })
}
```

P.S. Thanks to [@devnull69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030974/devnull69) for the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something that works server-side on Google Apps Script, try:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64 to Byte[]
  // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data);
  blob.setContentType(mimeString);
  return blob;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use

```
FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(Blob|File)
```

rather than

```
FileReader.readAsDataURL(Blob|File)
```

Comment: I have to store it as a DataURL for an indefinite period in localStorage, so using the alternative `ArrayBuffer` path won't work.