# Can I store videos as blobs in indexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb

I'm writing a web app that lives locally on a desktop computer and can be run in either Firefox or Chrome. It uses HTML5 and the local database storage: [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB). The users need to be able to download videos from an online storage and add them automatically to the app. I can't use ajax to grab and check for the files (since it's on the local filesystem so it fails the same origin), so they instead click a link that opens the remote-hosted videos in a new tab and prompts for saving to the computer. At this point, my app doesn't know where the files are or that they exist locally yet (and depends on the user saving it to the correct folder). Firefox also does not have a FileSystem API.

So instead, I want to make this more seamless to the user and have the app just download the blob data via JSONP into an indexedDB. But then it needs to be displayable via a `video` `source` or `object` flash tag. Is this possible? Can I set the source/data of those tags to be actual data and not a URL? So something like:

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
<video><source src="data:video/mp4;base64,iVBORw0..."/></video>
<video><object data="data:video/flv;base64,iVBORw0..."/></video>
```

Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can use a dataURL like you show to view the video.
specific browsers like specific formats, and that another thread, but it's possible.
the data url format is basically "data:"+mimeType+[base64 flag?]+","+ btoa(data).
so, you can easily make a dataURL from a string, if that's what you have.

i would recommend using an [objectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) instead, since videos can be quite large and dataURLs tend to perform poorly on big files.

you can create an object URL from a blob, which it sounds like you have.
if not, you can create the blob from an [array buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer), a [binary string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), a [dataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl) or an [ajax response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if the objectURL will work both in the `source` tag's "src" attribute and the `object` tag's "data" attribute?