# JQuery/javascript: how to get file input value?

Tags: jquery

I use this function:

```
function resize(file, max_width, max_height, compression_ratio, imageEncoding){
    var fileLoader = new FileReader(),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = null,
    imageObj = new Image(),
    blob = null;

    //create a hidden canvas object we can use to create the new resized image data
    canvas.id     = "hiddenCanvas";
    canvas.width  = max_width;
    canvas.height = max_height;
    canvas.style.visibility   = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    //get the context to use
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // check for an image then
    //trigger the file loader to get the data from the image
    if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
        fileLoader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        alert('File is not an image' + file);
    }

    // setup the file loader onload function
    // once the file loader has the data it passes it to the
    // image object which, once the image has loaded,
    // triggers the images onload function
    fileLoader.onload = function() {
        var data = this.result;
        imageObj.src = data;
    };

    fileLoader.onabort = function() {
        alert("The upload was aborted.");
    };

    fileLoader.onerror = function() {
        alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
    };


    // set up the images onload function which clears the hidden canvas context,
    // draws the new image then gets the blob data from it
    imageObj.onload = function() {

        // Check for empty images
        if(this.width == 0 || this.height == 0){
            alert('Image is empty');
        } else {

            context.clearRect(0,0,max_width,max_height);
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, max_width, max_height);


            //dataURItoBlob function available here:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl
            blob = dataURItoBlob(canvas.toDataURL(imageEncoding));

            //pass this blob to your upload function
            $( "#imgcaptmobile" ).append( '<img id="imagecaptmobile" src="' + blob + '" >');
        }
    };

    imageObj.onabort = function() {
        alert("Image load was aborted.");
    };

    imageObj.onerror = function() {
        alert("An error occured while loading image.");
    };

}
```

With this html code:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"form_titre_photo_capture_mobile\" placeholder=\"Titre\" class=\"texte_texte_photo_capture_mobile\" id=\"form_titre_photo_capture_mobile\">
                            <input type=\"file\" capture=\"camera\" accept=\"image/*\" id=\"takePictureField\" name=\"takePictureField\">
                            <canvas id=\"canvas_captimg\" width=\"487\" height=\"365\"></canvas>
                            <div id=\"imgcaptmobile\" style=\"display:hidden\"></div>
```

I can't get the "file" var to execute the function! I've tryied this:

```
$('#takePictureField').change(function(e) {
    var file = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val());
    resize(file, 487, 800, 70, "image/jpeg");
});
```

But the error on the console log is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined " (when calling if (file.type.match('image.*')) { )
So I suppose I don't call the file input value correctly?...

Answer (score 2):

That's because `val` returns a string object, the name of the selected file, not the `file` object that your code expects it, you need to use `files` property:

```
$('#takePictureField').change(function(e) {
    var file = this.files; // this.files[0] => the first selected file object
    resize(file, 487, 800, 70, "image/jpeg");
});
```

Comment: I've changed it. Now in console I have "FileList {0: File, length: 1, item: function}" and same error following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined

Comment: Edit: I've put the [0] and it seems to get the file. But I've still an error after: Uncaught ReferenceError: dataURItoBlob is not defined

Comment: @Recif You should pass the first selected file object, `this.files[0]`. Your function doesn't iterate through the `fileList` collection.

Comment: I've added the datauritoblob. Now error is : Uncaught ReferenceError: BlobBuilder is not defined

Comment: @Recif It seems you have borrowed that function and it calls other functions that are undefined in your code, is this true?

Comment: Yes! I've added it! Now the error is:  Uncaught ReferenceError: BlobBuilder is not defined

Comment: @Recif See the function's browser support here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder

Comment: Seems to be deprecated!! :-(( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl

Comment: Ok, I've seen it... But I don't know how to replac eit with blob new function :-(

Comment: @Recif Why don't you use a resize library?

Answer (score 0):

Have similar problem. I solved this.
In this approach jq returns array, and u can get any value, namefile for example:

```
uploadFieldHolder.on('change', function(e){
    var file = this.files; 
    console.log(file[0]['name']);
});
//It returns somefile.jpg
```