# FineUploader: Thumbnails on the fly clientside

Tags: javascript, image, fine-uploader

I am working on a FineUploader implementation. Special request is to **create thumbnails on the fly client-side** and then **upload those with the original image-upload**.

I have an implementation that works on FF, but does not seem to work on iOs. It looks like so:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
  button: document.getElementById(buttonID),
  request: {
    endpoint: '/up/load/a/' + $('section#ajax-viewport').data('albumid')
  },
  callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {

            // getFile obtains the file being uploaded
        file = this.getFile(id); 
            // create a thumbnail & upload it:
        ThumbDown(file, id, 200, fileName);
    },
  }
})
```

This code calls a function:

```
function ThumbDown(file, id, dimension, fileName) {

var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = function (ev) {
        var thumbnailDimensions; // object holding width & height of thumbnail
        var c=document.getElementById("canvas-for-thumbnails"); // must be a <canvas> element
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            // set thumbnail dimensions of canvas:
        thumbnailDimensions = calcThumbnailDimension (img.width, img.height, dimension )
        c.width = thumbnailDimensions.width;
        c.height = thumbnailDimensions.height;

        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        uploadThumbnail(c.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), //a base64 encoded representation of the image
                        id,               
                        fileName);       // we need filename to combine with mother-image on the server
    };
    img.src = e.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
} // end function
```

Finally the Thumbnail is uploaded with a dumb ajax-call:

```
function uploadThumbnail (base64encodedString, id, fileName) {

  $.post('/up/thumb',
  {
    img : base64encodedString,
    id: id,
    fileName: fileName
  },
  function(data) {});
}
```

**My questions:**

1) Currently I have two uploads: one for mother-image and another for thumbnail. I would like to combine this in one FineUploader call. However, I do not see a way to do this, due to the asynchronous nature of my thumbnail creation.

Am I missing something? Is this possible to reduce this to one FineUploader call?

2) This code uploads the thumbnails as a base64 encoded string. I would like to upload the thumbnail as an image (or as a `blob` ?). Perhaps by following [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) of Jeremy Banks. Would that work with FineUploader?

3) Are there other options/methods of FineUploader that I have missed but I should be using?

Any help is, *as always*, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit busy today (Sunday) but either I or someone else from the team will provide you with a detailed response either today or early in the business day tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks you, looking forward. Enjoy your Sunday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it is already trivial to upload the original image.  Fine Uploader takes care of that for you.  If I understand correctly, you want to also upload a scaled version of the image (which you have already generated).  I suggest you take the image you have drawn onto the canvas and convert it to a `Blob`.  Then, you can submit this `Blob` directly to Fine Uploader, where it will upload it for you.

For example, change the value of `uploadThumbnail` to this:

```
function uploadThumbnail(thumbnailDataUri, id, filename) {
    var imageBlob = getImageBlob(thumbnailDataUri, "image/jpeg"),
        blobData = {
            name: filename,
            blob: imageBlob
        };

    // This will instruct Fine Uploader to upload the scaled image
    uploader.addBlobs(blobData);
}  

function getImageBlob(dataUri, type) {
    var binary = atob(dataUri.split(',')[1]), 
        array = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: type});
}
```

Note: the `getImageBlob` function was adapted from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl/17876216#17876216).  If this works for you, be sure to upvote the answer I've linked to.

#### Server-side note

A `Blob` is pretty much a `File` without a `name` property.  Your server-side code will handle the upload of a `Blob` pretty much the same way as it does a `File` or form submit containing a `<input type="file">` form field.  The only noticeable difference to your server will be the filename parameter value in the Content-Disposition header of the multipart boundary containing the file.  To put it another way, your server may think the image is named "blob" or perhaps some other generic name, due to the way most browsers generate multipart encoded requests that contain `Blob` objects.  Fine Uploader should be able to get around that by explicitly specifying a file name for the browser to include in blob's Content-Disposition header, but this ability does not have wide browser support.  Fine Uploader gets around this limitation, to some degree, by including a "qqfilename" parameter with the request containing the actual name of the `Blob`.

#### Future native support for thumbnail generation & scaling

The plan is to add native support for thumbnail previews to Fine Uploader.  This is covered in feature requests [#868](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/868) and [#896](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/869).  There are other related feature requests open, such as [image rotation](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/707) and [validation related to images](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/646).  These features and other image-related features will likely be added to Fine Uploader in the very near future.  Be sure to comment on the existing feature requests or add additional requests if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, Ray. Yes, this works beautifully. Although I first made the mistake of running the `addBlobs()` method on the original `uploader`. That sends it into an infinite regression, creating thumbnails of thumbnails of thumbnails, ...

Comment: So we still needs two uploads. One for the mother-image. The other for the thumbnail. Then on the server, we must combine them. We can do so by sending some unique `id` along with the uploads. I guess this is unavoidable due to the asynchronous nature of the `File API`?

Comment: Yes, the best approach would be to associate them via common params.  One way would be to pass the UUID of the original image along with the thumbnail.  You can do that via the second parameter of the `addBlobs` API method, which accepts an object that will be transformed into parameters send along withe upload request for the blob/thumbnail.  Server-side, assuming you are already tracking the UUID for the original, you can easily connect the two.

Comment: @RayNicholus - is this answer still relevant or those *future updates* you've mentioned have changed it? thanks

Answer (score 3):

As of version 4.4 of FineUploader, as Ray Nicholus pointed out would eventually happen, this functionality has been baked into their framework.

Here is an example of setting the upload sizes when creating a FineUploader instance:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
...
scaling: {
    sizes: [
        {name: "small", maxSize: 100},
        {name: "medium", maxSize: 300}
    ]
}
});
```

[See their page on uploading scaled images](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html).

Comment: Nice feature. Looks well built.