# XHR + data URI doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

I use `XMLHttpRequest` to generate `Blob` from data URI using this code:

```js
function dataUrlToBlob(dataUrl, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open( 'GET',  dataUrl);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        callback( new Blob( [this.response], {type: 'image/png'} ) );
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Usage:

```js
dataUrlToBlob('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQIW2NkAAIAAAoAAggA9GkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=', callback);
```

Everything works fine in every browser except Safari. It throws such an error:

> [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQIW2NkAAIAAAoAAggA9GkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

The question is, are there any ways to make this approach working in Safari?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the exact same problem

Comment: Facing the exact same problem here too. Would love to know if you were able to get around this.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you use an XHR to do that? Just do it synchronously (answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27781331/1397319)):

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    if(typeof dataURI !== 'string'){
        throw new Error('Invalid argument: dataURI must be a string');
    }
    dataURI = dataURI.split(',');
    var type = dataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0],
        byteString = atob(dataURI[1]),
        byteStringLength = byteString.length,
        arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteStringLength),
        intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteStringLength; i++) {
        intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([intArray], {
        type: type
    });
}
```

Comment: I know that. But asynchronously is faster. That is not the question here.

Comment: @artch an asynchronous function will **always** be slower than a synchronous function doing the same thing.

Comment: Please don't start polemic about that. You don't know our exact use case, so it's just meaningless. XHR is capable to make use of multiple cores in parallel on some systems, so that in many concurrent operations environment it is **much** faster than the synchronous impementation using the same single JS process (or even using web workers, since they have messaging overhead).