# Passing Canvas to FineUploader not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am converting a base64 image string to canvas and then passing it to FineUploader but it throws an error. here is my coce:

```
dataURItoCanvas(uploadValue.base64String,
  function(canvas) {
    console.log(canvas);
    $('#uploader').fineUploader('addFiles', canvas);
  });

function dataURItoCanvas(dataURI, onsuccess) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onerror = onerror;
  img.onload = function onload() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (onsuccess) {
      onsuccess(canvas);
    }
    //canvas.toBlob(onsuccess);
  };
  img.src = dataURI;
  img.style = "display:none;";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

And it throws this error:

```
[FineUploader 4.2.2] Received 0 files or inputs.
jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at qq.FineUploader._prepareItemsForUpload (jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:16)
    at qq.FineUploader._prepareItemsForUpload (jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:17)
    at qq.FineUploader.addFiles (jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:16)
    at e.fn.init.j (jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:19)
    at Function.each (VM259 jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at e.fn.init.each (VM259 jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at e.fn.init.a.fn.fineUploader (jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:19)
    at 59?mobile=true&usernameOrEmail=idrees@fi.ae&password=password&v=1491980632786289328:4526
    at HTMLImageElement.onload (59?mobile=true&usernameOrEmail=idrees@fi.ae&password=password&v=1491980632786289328:4556)
_prepareItemsForUpload @ jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:16
_prepareItemsForUpload @ jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:17
addFiles @ jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:16
j @ jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:19
each @ VM259 jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
each @ VM259 jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
a.fn.fineUploader @ jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ 59?mobile=true&usernameOrEmail=idrees@fi.ae&password=password&v=1491980632786289328:4526
onload @ 59?mobile=true&usernameOrEmail=idrees@fi.ae&password=password&v=1491980632786289328:4556
```

With Blob i am getting same error too:

```
dataURItoCanvas(uploadValue.base64String, function (canvas) {
                                    console.log(canvas);
                                    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                                        $('#uploader').fineUploader('addFiles', { files: [blob] });
                                    });
                                });
```

Comment: @Kaiido https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles

Comment: Can you add your call to this addFiles method in the question ? And since it does accept Blobs, I still don't see why you pass through a canvas though... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl

Comment: @DotNetDreamer I tried debugging your code, I can't really test the upload but it seems to be working. However, I'm using "Fine Uploader 5.14.2" and not 4.2.2. The docs you linked are for this latest version. Have you tried it with this version?

Comment: @arcs i am getting warning with version number as well `[FineUploader 4.2.2] [object Object] is not a File or INPUT element!  Ignoring!`

Comment: @arcs the issue was outdated version which i had. I updated the library now its working fine `[Fine Uploader 5.14.2] Received 1 files.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in their docs [addFiles](https://docs.fineuploader.com/tag/4.2.2/api/methods.html#addFiles) from version 4.2.2 does not support the `CanvasWrapper`.

You should be fine when you update to the latest version (above 5.x.x)

As an alternative. `addBlobs()` is in 4.x.x (instead of `fineUploader('addFiles', { files: [] })`. 
So you could do something like

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
   $('#uploader').addBlobs( [blob] )
})
```

Comment: Great! i had an issue with toBlob() for compatibility reasons, i used canvas directly :)