# create and automatically force download file using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used **HTML file reader API** to read the file, 
and i got the below result

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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...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
```

How to write a file and force download the same file using the above string?

Comment: NOT a duplicate of those questions.

Comment: dunno .. it was tagged with "jquery" by you

Comment: Its not duplicate,It`s different question

Comment: What do you mean by "write a file" - on your server?

Comment: @mplungjan Javascript can create local files and they are downloaded as if they are remote -- no server involved, which is why a) this question is not a duplicate and b) explains what the OP is asking.  He has DATA URI that he wants the user to be able to download.

Comment: Yes I know JS can create local files but why create a local file and then download it? `<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x..." download="file.pdf">click</a>` should in principle also work...

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I don't have IE available to test with, but this was based off code that DOES work under IE.

My DataURL is an image so I had to change out the header.  You might not have to with your header -- but I left the code in place so you could see how it was done.

Thanks to IE, you need two different processes.

On IE, you convert your DataURI to a blob then download the blob.

On everything else, you would just download the URI itself.

```js
document.getElementById("d_button").addEventListener("click", download);

var filename="testfile";

// FROM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl
 
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
  // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

  // separate out the mime component
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

  // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
  var blob = new Blob([ab], {
    type: mimeString
  });
  return blob;

  // Old code
  // var bb = new BlobBuilder();
  // bb.append(ab);
  // return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
}



const dataURI = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==";

function download() {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // for IE
    const blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURI);
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, `${filename}.png`);
    return;
  }

  
  let dt = dataURI;
  /* Change MIME type to trick the browser to downlaod the file instead of displaying it */
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, "data:application/octet-stream");

  /* In addition to <a>'s "download" attribute, you can define HTTP-style headers */
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:application\/octet-stream/, `data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=${filename}.png`);

  this.href = dt;

}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="d_button">Download this</a>
```

Comment: The file is dowloaded, but does nothing. Why not use OP's file?

Comment: the file download, but does nothing.I need same original file which i read file using file reader API?

Answer (score 0):

```
I got answer using <a> tag force the download the file.

  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href',text );
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
    $("#page_header").removeClass('loader');
```

element.click();

Answer (score 0):

```
I got another answer using force the download the file.
using this link install file saver (https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

result : 'data:application/pdf;base64,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...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'

file_name : 'sample.jpg'

fileType : 'image/jpeg' 

**Function Call**

this.urltoFile(result, file_name, fileType)
          .then(function(file){
              var blob = new Blob ([file], {type: fileType});
              FileSaver.saveAs(blob, file_name);
              this.loading = false;
          });

**function definition**

urltoFile(url, filename, mimeType){
  return (fetch(url)
    .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
    .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename, {type:mimeType});})
)},
```