# Is there a built in function to extract image data from Data URI?

Tags: javascript, data-uri

Specification says

```
data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>
```

Considering this it is easy to split the uri after "," to retrieve the image data.
Is there a built in function for the same in javascript or jquery ?

Comment: You could just do `.split('base64;')` and get the `encoded data` in `[1]` position of the result

Comment: In what format do you want the image data? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12168909/1048572) for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use `replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '')` for example

```
var encodedData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAARCAYAAADdRIy+AAAB0UlE';

encodedData = encodedData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '');
```