# Can't send request with FormData (nuxt.js, vue.js, axios)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js, form-data

I've custom vuex store action to send data to API server:

```
updateAvatar({commit, dispatch}, data) {
  return this.$axios.put(`/users/${this.$auth.user.id}/logo`, data)
}
```

Here is I sent request to server:

```
let data = new FormData()
let blob = this.$toBlob(imgDataUrl)
data.set('key', 'value')
data.append('avatar', blob, 'avatar.png')

this.$store.dispatch('user/updateAvatar', data)
```

But when I check request on API server then request no has any fields.

How I can send correctly request with fields and file?

Comment: i woul use `POST` request. Then you need to add in the header `application: "multipart-form-data"`. On the backend its good to google about `multer`

Comment: @Ifaruki nope, don't add the header. The browser handles `FormData` post bodies for you and sets the appropriate headers, including the require mime-boundary

Comment: Looks ok from the client-side (except we have no idea what `$toBlob` does). What does your server-side code look like?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300351/7496039) is content of `$toBlob` method @Phil

Comment: When I tried with `POST` method works but with `PUT` doesn't work. Why? @Ifaruki

Comment: how does your API endpoint looks like?

Comment: You must send the media file separately from the text data. Go to my blog and you will find an example of how to upload images to server using Nuxt/axios

Comment: I endpoit method is `PUT` and looks like this `/api/users/{id}/avatar`. I use Laravel in my server app. @Ifaruki