# How to get the image that is in a html img tag in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, blob

I have a html string that contains a image tag. I want to get that image and convert to blob and then a file.Is it possible?

html string is sth like this:

```
  <p><img class="logo" src="assets/alphaRoute/LogoOnly-01.svg" alt=""></p>
```

Comment: So you need to parse the HTML, find the element, read the attribute value, convert it to a blob, and then convert it to a "file" (whatever that means in the context of angular). Which **specific** part of that is is causing you trouble?

Comment: converting to blob @Quentin

Comment: Then you should rewrite your question to focus on that.

Comment: Also you could try searching since it took me all of 10 seconds to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl) duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question.I pasted wrong html string.I have just the image local source address.