# Uploading image to azure blob storage using React

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to upload image from react to azure blob storage but the request fails with error :

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')
> at BlockBlobClient.uploadFile

here is a sample of code trying to achieve it :

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

const account = process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
const sas = process.env.REACT_APP_SAS_TOKEN;

const containerName = 'usercontainer';
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/?${sas}`,
);

export const uploadToBlob = async (file) => {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  const blobName = file.src + new Date().getTime();
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(file.src);
  console.log(
    `Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`,
    uploadBlobResponse.requestId,
  );
  
};
```

Comment: What kind of object is `file`?

Comment: @GauravMantri its an object holding the src of the file {src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S96RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg…HyjB9RiumP+u/4CP5CsrXf9Rc/wC8n/oS16WVfEZVvgZ//9k='}

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

1. You are calling `uploadFile` method which is only available in NodeJS runtime and is not available in the browser. Please see documentation of this method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-uploadfile.
2. The method you would want to use is [`uploadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blockblobclient-uploaddata) which expects an object of type `Blob`. Considering you have a data URL, you would need to create a `Blob` object out of it. Please see this question regarding converting a data URL to Blob: [Blob from DataURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! the solution was to use uploadData instead of uploadFile and convert the DataURL to Blob .