# Post a byte array (Blob)

Tags: javascript, post, arrays

I need to encrypt a file before posting it. In WebKit, I know that with FileWriter, I could just rewrite the file then post it, but my solution needs to be crossbrowser compatible.

I could also take all my blobs and pass them to a flash uploader, but I would create another problem.

Is there a method in javascript to post an ArrayBuffer or a byte array as a file?

Right now, I think about Ajax, but could it handle 200MB+ files?

[Edit]

Interesting:
[How to convert dataURL to file object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850276/how-to-convert-dataurl-to-file-object-in-javascript)

It seems possible to post Blob via Ajax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript#246813
Not sure if this is what you are after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked again the above link, and following the caniuse.com table, BlobBuilder is compatible with all current browsers, so it is possible to

1. Take a bytearray or any other data
2. Convert it to base64
3. Convert it to blob
4. Send it as a normal file with Ajax/xhr/FormData using your favorite method