# turning canvas.toDataURL DOMString url into a blob,

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i am using **cropperjs** to crop images

Using the method `getCroppedCanvas` to get reference to the cropped canvas image

Using the canvas method `canvas.toDataURL` to compress the images into a jpeg files.

I don't use `canvas.toBlob` as its browser support is not clear.

My question is how can i turn the string i get from `canvas.toDataURL` into a blob so i can later use it in formData.

**Update**

server expect form data - multi-part

Answer (score 7):

One method that I used while working on some tool is to convert the dataURL to Blob using this function:

```
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
}
```

And then you can send the Blob to the server using native xhr like this:

```
var blob = dataURLtoBlob(dataURI);
var fd = new FormData();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ();

fd.append ('file', blob);
xhr.open('POST', '/endpoint', true);

xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.log('error');
}

xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('success')
}

xhr.send (fd);
```

The blob builder code is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407840/2386736

Answer (score 0):

use `canvas.toDataURL` to generate an JPEG image:

```
var JPEG_QUALITY=0.5;
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', JPEG_QUALITY).replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
```

And then send it to AJAX as data-multi-part:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php/upload.php',
    data: dataUrl,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){            
    }
});
```

Depending on what your server side expects to receive.

**By the way:** You wrote *"I don't use canvas.toBlob as its browser support is not clear"* - You can see the browser support [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob):

[image]

Comment: I've updated the question, the server expect normal form data multi-part