# Send image via formData and fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a post request with form data to send  an image like this via fetch API:

[image]

```
function uploadImage(image) {
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("upload", image);
      fetch('/accounts/upload-image', {
          method: 'post',
          body: data,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

But it seems that I missed something? I can not get the data in my server!

Using Postman with no errors it's working So there is something wrong with my fetch function in front end.

The binary data (image) I send to `uploadImage(image)` function is like this:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: It looks like on the server you accept file upload but you send data as POST variable using data URI. Check this answer [How do I upload a file with the JS fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40826943/387194) don't look at the accepted answer, it's totally wrong and incomplete.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850276/how-to-convert-dataurl-to-file-object-in-javascript for how to convert the `data:` URI to a `Blob` so you can upload it.

Comment: If you don't have a file and you want to send Canvas Data URI to server as file upload see [How to convert dataURL to file object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261048/387194)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node/Express file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload)