# Send image generated in frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I got this third party lib which generates a screenshot.

[image]

I want to save this on my server. I'm using Axios.It's probably something with blobs, arraybuffers etc?

1. How do I send it?

   Axios.post('/api/saveimage', { ??? })
2. Using NodeJs express on backend. How do I save this to a physical image file?

Comment: Try popping `data.dataUrl` into a base64 to image convertor (a quick Google would turn this up: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), then once you're sure it's base64 data you're dealing with, a quick google will give you an npm package that specialises in turning base64 data into an image

Answer (score 0):

Well at the frontend you need to send it like this:

```
let formData = new FormData()

formData.append("image", file)

axios.post("/api/saveimage",formData)
```

At the first step you create a `FormData`, then you append the file. In this case i named the file `image`. Now lets go to the next step. You will need `multer` on your nodejs side.

```
npm i multer
```

The first think you need to do, is to create an middleware:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const whitelist = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/webp"];
const storeImages = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: async function (req, file, cb) {
    if (!whitelist.some((type) => type === file.mimetype)) {
      return cb(new Error("File is not allowed"), "/");
    }

    cb(null, "your/destination/path");
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    let [name] = file.originalname.split(".");

    cb(null, name + ".png");
  },
});

exports.uploadImageStorage = multer({
   storage: storeImages,
});
```

Here watch out: Your destination path should exist. Also dont forget an extension for your  file in this case `.png`

Now you create your route:

```
const { uploadImageStorage } = require("../yourstorage")
app.post("/api/saveimage", uploadImageStorage.single("image"), (req, res) => {
   let file = req.file
   let path = file.path
})
```

Here you need to know at `uploadImageStorage.single("image")` i used `image` like i used it in `formData.append("image", file)` they need to be the same.

Now you can save the path of your file into a database. You can also transform your image with `sharp` if you want

From my experience if you have folder called `static` and you have a image inside of it like `photo.png` you usually get the photo with `localhost:3000/photo.png` and not with `localhost:3000/static/photo.png`

You will need to remove `static` from your path if you have this setup. Otherwise if you try to display the image on the frontend you wont see it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In formData.append("image", file), what is file? Is that the content in the screenshot in my question? All of it or part of it?

Comment: @Joe its the file from your change event. You can get the file from the event with `let [file] = event.target.files`

Comment: As i said in my question, the screenshot is generated from a third party lib. I don't upload it myself. The content I receive, I posted in the question.

Comment: @Joe then convert your DataUrl to an file. If you google for "convert dataurl to file" you will get this at the top result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850276/how-to-convert-dataurl-to-file-object-in-javascript